# change color of replaceAll comma with arrow

Tags: jquery, replaceall

I have used `replaceAll` function which is perfectly working - I want to change the color of arrows.
How can I do that?  Please help I am a beginner.

**Here is my jQuery code**

```
let network = '';
if ($('#depsTo').val()) {
    network = $('#depsTo').val();
    network = network.toString().replaceAll(',','--->');
    console.log("NETWORK : " + network);
    $('#networkHeading').html(network);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use html! You could use span, as I have in this snippet:

```js
let network = 'This, is, a, test, string';
  network = network.toString().replaceAll(',','<span style="color:red">---></span>');
$('#networkHeading').html(network);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="networkHeading"></div>
```

Comment: i want to add border in network how can i do that?

Comment: @Batool you can change the css class or `style=` value in the provided answer.  However that's beyond the scope of the original question and you should accept this answer.

Comment: its coming on all value border, i want one by one on network variable

Comment: @Batool you should specify all your requirements in your question. Also, it's not clear what you want. You want a border around each word in the list? Around the whole list? Around each arrow?

Comment: around each word not arrow..words which are coming in Network variable

Comment: this code is returning this, ABC ---> GHQ---->NGH , i want border on ABC,GHQ,NGH only..please help

Answer (score 0):

If you want same color again and again then use this

```
$('#' + id).css({"color":"blue"});
```

And if you want different color every time then use this in for loop

```
 var r = Math.random() * 256
 var g = Math.random() * 256
 var b = Math.random() * 256

$('#' + id).css({"color":`"rgba(${r},${g},${b},${a})"`});
```